# Identify element in espresso by resource-id from UI Automator viewer

Tags: java, kotlin, android-espresso, android-uiautomator

I have following resource-id in UI Automator viewer, but I'm not sure how can use it in matcher when running espresso tests. Example

```
resource-id: com.app.cooking.debug:id/design_menu_item_text
```

How should I transform this id to Espresso id to make sure I can run matcher:

```
Espresso.onView(ViewMatchers.withId("com.app.cooking.debug:id/design_navigation_view")).check(ViewAssertions.matches(ViewMatchers.isDisplayed()))
```

P.S. I don't have that id in `R.id.myId`

Answer (score 1):

This should work
   Espresso.onView(ViewMatchers.withId(R.id.design_navigation_view)).check(ViewAssertions.matches(ViewMatchers.isDisplayed()))